# C++ makefile will compile only first 3 entries

Tags: c++, makefile

Good day,
recently i switched from jamfile to makefile. The reason of this switch is that i think that jamfile does not really cooperate with armadillo and openmp libraries. I have code divided into multiple *.h and *.cpp files.

```
# makefile for my PhD thesis
# Created by Michal Buday, no copyrights
# Datum: 01.07.2016
SHELL    := /bin/sh
SRC      := methods
BIN      := bin

CXX      := g++           # GNU C++ compiler
CXXFLAGS := -Wall       
ARMAF    := -larmadillo   # ARMADILLO matrix library

OPT      := -O
# GGG      := -g # for debugging
                 # bash$ gdp ${program name} core
# ===============================================================================================
# standard stuff
all:  coord_trans.o geodetic_functions.o geo_models.o interpolations.o \
      legendre.o loadpoints.o physical_constants.o sphere_int.o \
      3Dtransformations.o    

LIBOBJ = coord_trans.o geodetic_functions.o geo_models.o interpolations.o \
     legendre.o loadpoints.o physical_constants.o sphere_int.o \
     3Dtransformations.o #topo_corrections.o

geodetic_functions.o: $(SRC)/geodetic_functions.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/geodetic_functions.h -o $(BIN)/$@

geo_models.o: $(SRC)/geo_models.h $(SRC)/legendre.h $(SRC)/geodetic_functions.h \
              $(SRC)/physical_constants.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/geo_models.h -o $(BIN)/$@

interpolations.o: $(SRC)/interpolations.cpp $(SRC)/interpolations.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/interpolations.cpp -o $(BIN)/$@

legendre.o: $(SRC)/legendre.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/legendre.h -o $(BIN)/$@

loadpoints.o: $(SRC)/loadpoints.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/loadpoints.h -o $(BIN)/$@

sphere_int.o: $(SRC)/sphere_int.h $(SRC)/sphere_int.cpp
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/sphere_int.cpp $(ARMAF) -o $(BIN)/$@

#topo_corrections.o: $(SRC)/topo_corrections.h $(SRC)/geodetic_functions.h
#   $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/topo_corrections.h $(ARMAF)

3Dtransformations.o:  $(SRC)/3Dtransformations.h $(SRC)/3Dtransformations.cpp
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/3Dtransformations.cpp $(ARMAF) -o $(BIN)/$@

coord_trans.o: $(SRC)/coord_trans.h $(SRC)/geodetic_functions.h
    $(CXX) $(OPT) -c $(SRC)/coord_trans.h  -o $(BIN)/$@

main.o: $(LIBOBJ)
    $(CXX) $(OPT) $(BIN)/$(LIBOBJ) -o $@ $(ARMAF)


# ======================================================================== #
#


clean:
    rm *.o
```

The dependencies are:

```
# coord_trans.h  << geodetic_functions.h
# geodetic_functions.h << armadillo
# geo_models.h << legendre.h geodetic_functions.h physical_constants.h
# interpolations.h << std
# legendre.h << std
# loadpoints.h << std
# physical_constants.h << define only
# sphere_int.h << armadillo
# topo_corrections.h << geodetic_functions.h
# 3Dtransformations.h << armadillo
```

But when i call

> make
>   in terminal it creates only the first 3 entries in makefile and also the size of binary files is over 107 MB (the code itself has 100k or less). What am i missing?

Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to use `$<` (first dependancie) for your `-c` argument instead of repeating it.

Also, I would advise to build the list of object files given the cpp files (`wildcard` function?).

Finally, you may want to try to replace `$(BIN)/$(LIBOBJ)` by `$(FULLPATH_LIBOBJ)` constructed using:

```
FULLPATH_LIBOBJ = $(addprefix $(BIN)/, $(LIBOBJ))
```

Not sure this changes anything, but your makefile looks complicated to me, whereas it should be much simpler!
Also, it is hard to help you compiling the project without the project itself.